# Separate matrix based on cumulative sum of column criteria (MATLAB)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting

I have a dataset something like the following:

```
a = [1 11; 2 16; 3 9; 4 13; 5 8; 6 14];
```

I am looking to separate into several Matrices by the following criteria:
Starting with the first column, construct sets where the sum of the second row is in the range `19`-to-`25`.

So the output would be something like this:

```
a1 = [1 11; 3 9]
a2 = [2 16; 5 8]
a3 = [6 14]
```

Where a1=20, a2=24, and a3 does not meet criteria but is the last.

Could this be contained and output from a FOR loop?

Edit: Criteria of how to combine: I am looking to start at the beginning (first row) and add to the next row. If the sum is greater than 25, that row would be skipped till the next iteration. Each iteration should output a seperate matrix (a1, a2, a3).

Comment: Do you mean column or row? Because the sum of the second columns is: 12, 13, 20, respectively.

Comment: I edited the matrix -- had the columns and rows switched. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JahnnyT: Would you also want triplets, or only pairs?

Comment: So there are many possibilities. You chose the "first" match. It might be worth investigating if there is an optimal solution with no left overs. eg consider adding a 8th line [3,4] - then a3=[6 14;3 4] would be no solution - but a2=[2 16,3 4], a3=[6 14; 5 8] would give you a third "pair". Though that problem is quite nasty.

Comment: @Jonas : Can be any type of set, pairs, triples, or even more.

Comment: @bdecaf : I am looking to combine the first match. Starting with row 1 it will search each row until it is within the criteria ... then remove that from the Matrix. Then it will only skip a row if the sum is over the max criteria of 25.

Comment: Ok. I was not sure by your description if this "inefficiecy" was on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have some useful pseudo code for you.

For one I would not modify the matrix by removing columns. Rather I would keep a list of used columns.

I would use the summing like this:

```
used = false(1,num lines)
for i=1:num lines
  if used(i) continue
  curr_use = i
  for j=i+1
     if used(j) continue
     if cant_add(j) continue
     Concat j to curr_use
  end
  used(curr_use) = true
end
```

Comment: This will be very helpful! I will have to try coding this. Thanks!